# validate/change input value with php

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to validate and change the input value from a wordpress search form.

```
<?php $unique_id = esc_attr( uniqid( 'search-form-' ) ); ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></span>
    </label>


    <input type="search" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />


    <button type="submit" class="search-submit">
<?php echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'search' ) ); ?><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></span></button>
</form>
```

I used this code to change value but it aint working ;-(

this should remove all characters with and after TEST but it aint.

Am i missing something?

At the end i want to validate the input value and when it contains specific words it needs to be changed into clean search strings.

Answer (score 0):

What excactly you have tried? It looks like the normal searchform of Wordpress.

To modify the query you have to hook into pre_get_posts function:

```
function your_filter($query) {
    if (!$query->is_search) {
        return $query;
    }

    // your code here

    return $query;
}
//hook
add_filter('pre_get_posts','your_filter');
```

For escaping the search value you can do something like this:

```
value="<?php echo doWhatEverYouWantFunction(get_search_query()); ?>"
```

Comment: i tried this: `$query = substr($query, 0, strpos($query, "&catalogRefIds="));`   but i get a error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/voordnl/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 467`

Comment: @Maarten Query is an Object look here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query